# limit of quotient of two vanishing sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Given two strictly positive vanishing sequences, is it correct to say that the limit of their quotient always exists, finite or infinite? I think yes, just by considering the three possible cases concerning their growth (either they grow approximately the same - finite non zero limit - or one outgrows the other - 0 or infinite limit). Am I implicitly adding some sort of regularity not included in the hypothesis? Maybe a good way to do this more formally would be proving that the liminf and limsup are always the same...
EDIT: I understand that the term 'vanishing' is not specific enough. What I was really thinking of is vanishing with strict monotonicity. I like all the answers so far but it seems to me they lack the monotonicity Perhaps adding this regularity condition makes the statement true?

Answer (score 3):

No. Interlock two different sequences that converge to $0$ with different magnitudes into, say, the numerator, and let the denominator be sandwiched in between them.

You will find that the whole sequence has subsequences always above $1$ and and always below $1$, so there can be no limit.

---

Example for completion sake:

Let $a_{2n+1} = 3/n$ and $a_{2n} = 1/n$.
Let $b_{2n+1} = b_{2n} = 2/n$.
Let $c = a/b$, so that $c_{2n+1} = 3/2$ and $c_{2n} = 1/2$.

Comment: Thank you. What if we require vanishing with strict monotonicity? Would that make the statement true?

Comment: You can still do the same thing.

Comment: A visual way would be as follows: draw a 'line' that is always going down and draw another line that is also always going down, but is sometimes above the first and sometimes below. Now let one be your numerator and let one be your denominator. If you're worried about them being always positive, just make sure the lines all go down to $-\infty$ and consider the $\exp$ of them as your sequences for numerators and denominators.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not true. Take $a_n=\frac{1}{2^n}$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{2^n}$ for $n$ even and $b_n=\frac{2}{2^n}$ for $n$ odd. Then these both vanish, but their quotient is $1$ for even $n$ and $\frac{1}{2}$ for odd $n$, i.e. it does not converge

Comment: The sequences are required to be strictly positive.

Comment: Oh yeah, I altered my example

Comment: Thank you. What if we require vanishing with strict monotonicity? Would that make the statement true?

Comment: No, take $a_n=\frac{1}{2^n}$, and let $b_n=a_n$ for $n$ odd and $b_n=\frac{1.5a_n}{2}$ for $n$ even, then both $a_n$ and $b_n$ are strictly decreasing, but their quotient does not converge as before

Answer (score 1):

Pick your favourite positive sequence $u_n$ with limit $0$ and define $$v_n=\cases{u_n &$n$ even\\2u_n& $n$ odd}$$
Then $v_n>0$, $\lim v_n=0$ and $\frac {v_n}{u_n}$ keeps taking values $1$ and $2$.

Comment: Thank you. What if we require vanishing with strict monotonicity? Would that make the statement true?